# touchesBegan in UIView not being called

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview

I know that this question must have been answered plenty of times already, but I have no idea why the `touchesBegan:` is not called in my `UIView`.

Before I added it in my app, I made a trial project to do some tests. What I did was subclass a `UIView` where the `touchesBegan:` is implemented and add this as a subview of another view. The superview has a button which shows the subclassed `UIView` once clicked. Everything works as expected.

However, when I did the same thing in my existing app, the `touchesBegan:` method, as well as the `touchesMoved:`, were never called. Can anyone explain what could be preventing the methods from being called?

Comment: is the user interaction enabled for your view?

Comment: When I enabled the user interaction, it still doesn't recognize the touches. Still though, in my trial project I didn't even enabled the user interaction, yet it still recognize the touches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just found the answer to this. I realised that the superview of the `UIView` has the `userInteraction` set to disabled (which is the default value). So when I enabled the `userInteraction` of the superview, the touches are now recognised.

Answer (score 8):

In my case `background = UIColor.clearColor()` was the reason why `touchesBegan` was not called. Its obviously not called on transparent elements.

Comment: I spent 2 hours of debugging until I found this answer! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling on this problem for a while... and i figure it out. I think that the *touchesBegan* override function listen on the main view: the first one on the storyboard tree of the ViewController! I would love to post an image of my storyboard to be more clear, but i can't! ;)

Anyway, **IF** you have subviews, they may covers the main view... in this manner the touch wont "reach" the main view.

To avoid this you'll have to set the **Background** property in the **Attribute Inspector** to **Default** for **ALL THE SUBVIEWS**. In this way the background will be transparent and the touch will be able to reach the main view.

If you don't want to set the background to transparent there is something you can do:

-Add an outlet of your last view (with background set)

-Add a *tap gesture recognizer* to it

-Handle the tap disposing the keyboard

ES.

In properties:

```
//The last view's outlet
@IBOutlet weak var ContainerView: UIView!
```

In viewDidLoad():

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
self.ContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Outside:

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that Touches weren't being triggered when my Stack View was embedded inside of a Scroll View.  I did check that User Interaction was Enabled, but still, it was not detecting touch.  Perhaps there's a way to detect Touch inside of a Scroll View, but I'm too lazy to figure it out and it is not needed for my use case, so I just removed the Scroll View and touches are detected again!